# Android application hangs. Why?

Tags: android, performance, crash

sometimes touch wiz exception appears. I  have use multiple service s and thread

```
Suspending all threads took: 56.213ms
Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46481(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 424(6MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 97MB/113MB, paused 6.164ms total 249.603ms
```

above is my logcat in case of touchwiz Exception

i am also getting message free garbage collection.and also for heap size.
how do i fix it?
please help me

Comment: Please see how to ask questions on debugging/crash on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
It should have a specific scenario or code snippet which will help users to answer your question.

Comment: Do you have tablayouts and asynctasks in your app?

Comment: yes I have  tablayouts and asynctasks in my app.

Answer (score 2):

check out [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html),

what you should understand is the `Services` doesn't have its own `process` it runs on the `main thread process`, so if you are doing some heavy `task` then create a `thread` inside the `service` otherwise your service which is doing heavy task will bog the `main thread`,

other things which you might want to consider.

you are running low on memory for your `application` as your app consumes more of space allocated to your application by the system.

put this attribute  `android:largeHeap="true"` in the the `<application/>`  atgin the `manifest.xml` file

for example

```
 <application
    android:name="support.classes.StartUp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true" // you are increasing the heap space for the app 
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeTest">
```

if you simple want to free some space it would be better to let Android system handle it which knows the best

```
System.gc()
```

call garbage collector before you do any memory consuming task as that will free some space for you. if you try to call this after your task then it serves no purpose

Comment: please  check my edit.i have edit logcat details.

Comment: @NehaRathore, i believe you are doing a lot of work in your services, fixing that Would be better. Consider using render script or Opening a separate thread inside the service while you are doing the heavy work